# d3 - aggregate data giving a "step" value

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I am trying to think about semantic zooming and data aggregation to some rendering/panning SVG's issues.

So whenever my view range (x domain) gets too big and its data get's too many elements I draw some "merged/aggregated"new data that represents my origianal one.

So, one way of reducing my data is aggregating it according to an "step" value.

Let's say I have an x.domain([1,1000]) and a filtered data with 1000 elements (from position 1 to 1000). I'll set this 1000 position/elements as my fixed amount of elements to be rendered.

IF the user zooms out to a new x.domain([1,2000)], instead of getting 2000 data elements, I'd like to aggregate (mean or median) somehow my data. In this case I'd have an step of 2 (i.e. domain size / fixed # of elements OR 2000/1000=2)

It seems to be a reasonable thing to do once too many rendered elements is slow and not a good thing to do using SVG. It can get big easily.

So my idea would be (in this scenario): aggregate values by step.

Let's say I have this data object:

> {position:1, value:8},
>       {position:2, value:10},
>       {position:3, value:10},
>       {position:4, value:12},
>       {position:5, value:14},
>       {position:6, value:16},
>       ...

the resulting agreggated object would be:

> {position:1+2/step, value:8+10/step},
>   {position:3+4/step,value:10+12/step}, 
>   {position:5+6/step, value:14+16/step},
>   ...

This way I'll always keep 1000 elements to be rendered. And once my samplying rate=1, it will still gives a good idea of the data.

My question is:

what would be the best solution to aggregate my data this way ? (once it is not aggreagated by an specific field (i.e. month, country, etc)).

Will d3.nest() be the right choise ? what about crossfilter ?

Any thoughts and/or help is highly appreciated.

Cheers.,
D

Answer (score 1):

While *crossfilter* is definitely a good option, I prefer a lightweight library [*simplify.js*](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/), especially if you are dealing with line charts or your data contain extreme points that may get filtered by your *step* function. *simplify.js* reduces your data so that the chart looks visually similar to the one created using all data points.

Comment: simplify.js seems to be a nice (and fast) library indeed. I think I'd like to control the logic of it once I have several data types (and some of then have sampling rate != 1), so I can control and change the logic based on that. The problem is: I have no idea on how to use crossfilter or d3.nest() to act the way I need it :/